# Deleting specific rows with a pattern[start and end indicators] from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

[image: Sample Dataset]

I want to remove all rows between "5. Demand Disputed" and "Total Demand Disputed" from their respective columns. I have tried

```
 grepl
 gsub
```

but not able to achieve the desire output.Kindly guide.

Comment: could you please `dput(data$V1)`

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Please try to clarify your problem and come up with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a toy example...

```
df <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:10],b=LETTERS[3:12],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
limits <- c("E","H")

sapply(df,function(x){
  del.min <- grep(limits[1],x)
  del.max <- grep(limits[2],x)
  x[del.min:del.max] <- ""
  return(x)})

      a   b  
 [1,] "A" "C"
 [2,] "B" "D"
 [3,] "C" "" 
 [4,] "D" "" 
 [5,] ""  "" 
 [6,] ""  "" 
 [7,] ""  "I"
 [8,] ""  "J"
 [9,] "I" "K"
[10,] "J" "L"
```

Comment: Thank You! I was wondering how to set index or put a indicator to remove it. Got my ans.

Comment: It seems that `grep` is not necessary. `which` should work fine

Comment: @Sotos - I used `grep` because in the image there seems to be some extra text after `Total Demand Disputed`, so I think it is a more robust solution than `which`.

Comment: I meant on your data set. But I agree about robustness

Answer (score 2):

Use grep to create an index vector between the two lines.

```
x[-c(grep("5. Demand Disputed", x$V1) : grep("Total Demand Disputed", x$V1), ]
```

Explanation

`grep` " returns a vector of the indices of the elements of x that yielded a match" (`?grep`)

So, you can simply create an integer vector between the two lines that match the two strings by `:`.

Comment: `Error in x$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: I cannot help you with that error, since you didn't add data. Please share a little of the data, so we have a reproducible example to work on.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I got the solution. You were right about creating index vector.